# Link expire when a data modified in it

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

Design a jsp page,firstly a mail is sent to a person,a link is sent with that mail content which  have a query string contain a password, a jsp page is open by click on it,but if changes will occur in jsp page,then a link is terminate permanently otherwise it will expire in 2 days and new link is generated after two days.

Here is my code

```
<p>To get an extension 
<a href=one.jsp?uid='"+ rs3.getString(2)+ "'&customer="+ alias +">click here< /a></p>
```

There is no space in my code between `<a>`.
uid is random password and how this query string parameter fetch in jsp file.

Comment: complete question and explanation in a single line.

Comment: how to expire a link in jsp,if changes has been done on that jsp page and if not then link will expire in two days bydefault.

Comment: which type "change" in JSP page?

Comment: in jsp page i have a submit button,if that button is clicked,link is expire and not in use.

Comment: I could not get your problem. please explain the complete scenario.

Comment: Are you looking for "forgot password" like thing?

Comment: there is no password but a link which is send via an email,if person click on that link a jsp page is open and it has submit button,if submit button is clicked then that link cannot open that jsp page and display page is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the query string parameter.

```
request.getParameter("uid");
```

Comment: it shows empty result set but in my database,it contain some value

Comment: ohh i find the error for this problem.But thanks for your time.

Comment: still have a problem in link expiration